# Конструктор класса окружность

Tags: c++

нужно определить находится ли некоторая точка с координатами x,y внутри окружности. не могу понять что написать в int main(то, что там щас недоразумение, просто чтоб было), заранее благодарю

```
class Circle
{
private:
    double x, y, r;
public:
    Circle(double r, double x = 0, double y = 0):r(r),x(x),y(y){}
    Circle(const Circle&) = default;
    ~Circle()             = default;

    bool isIn(double xx, double yy)
    {
        return (xx-x)*(xx-x)+(yy-y)*(yy-y) <= r*r;
    }

 int main()  {
    int r=20;
    int x=10;
    int y=10;
if (x*x+y*y<=r*r) {
    cout<<"ne nahoditsya"<< endl;
}
else if  (x*x+y*y>=r*r) {
    cout<<"nahoditsya"<< endl;
}
}
}
```

Comment: в int main как минимум надо написать вызов метода isIn() экземпляра класса Circle. Всё остальное - по заданию.

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, раз уж передран мой код отсюда — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1345808/195342 — придется не просто разжевать, но и проглотить...

```
int main()  
{
    double r=20;
    double x=10;
    double y=10;
    cout<< (Circle(r).isIn(x,y) ? "" : "ne ") << "nahoditsya\n";
}
```

Конечно, если центр окружности в начале координат...